# PHP password_hash not matching

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a password being hashed and saved in to a SQL database with the following code:

```
$passHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

It is saved in to a field called 'password' with the type VARCHAR(255)

I then use the following code to log the user in

```
$dbconn = OpenCon();
$username = $_POST['usernameInput'];
$password = $_POST['passInput'];
$passHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$school = $_POST['schoolInput'];
$sqlstmnt2 = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND school = :school';
$stmtUsr2 = $dbconn -> prepare($sqlstmnt2);
$stmtUsr2 -> bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmtUsr2 -> bindValue(':school', $school);
$stmtUsr2 -> execute();
$rows = $stmtUsr2 -> fetchAll();
$n = count($rows);
if($n<1 or !password_verify($rows[0]['password'], $passhash)) {
        echo 'No user account exists. Please check your credentials'."<br>";
}
else{
       $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
       header("Location: home.php");
}
```

When I run it and enter a details I know to be correct, the password_verify function is not returning that they are the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`PASSWORD_VERIFY()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) From the Manual The other part of the `password_hash()/password_verify()` pair

Comment: Please check the usage examples. You aren't verifying the actual password but a new hash. If `password_hash()` would always produce the same hash you wouldn't need `password_verify()`, you could simply use `===`.

Comment: Ah, so I see that I should be passing $password in to the password_verify and not the actual hash. I did that and edited the question but it's still not accepting it

Comment: `password_verify($_POST['passInput'], $rows[0]['password'])`

Comment: I've reverted your edit and answered the question as originally posed.

Comment: I notice you are doing a `$rows = $stmtUsr2 -> fetchAll();` How many rows can be returned by your query, if its more than one, then how do you know you are checking the right users password?? If you can return only one, then dont use fetchAll as that just confuses

Comment: @IMSop If I could have found that Duplicate I would have used it, but I couldnt

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly. I failed to understand that the order in which you pass the values mattered

Answer (score 1):

If we break down the code, and look at the main flow without the details, we have something like this:

```php
$passwordFromUserInput = getPasswordFromUserInput(); // $password in your code
$passHash = password_hash($passwordFromUserInput, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$passwordHashFromDb = getPasswordHashFromDb(); // $rows[0]['password'] in your code
if ( password_verify($passwordHashFromDb, $passHash) ) {
   // success
}
```

(I'm assuming that although the database column is called `password`, it isn't actually storing the raw password, which would defeat the purpose of hashing it!)

But if we look at the signature of `password_verify` [in the PHP manual](https://php.net/password_verify), it looks like this:

```php
password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )
```

You're passing in two hashes, but it wants a password (the one the user attempted to log in with) and a hash (the one you've stored). So the corrected version of the simplified code is this:

```php
$passwordFromUserInput = getPasswordFromUserInput(); // $password in your code
$passwordHashFromDb = getPasswordHashFromDb(); // $rows[0]['password'] in your code
if ( password_verify($passwordFromUserInput, $passwordHashFromDb) ) {
   // success
}
```

Or more succinctly:

```php
if ( password_verify($_POST['passInput'], $rows[0]['password']) ) {
   // success
}
```

The key to understanding this is that the function is not just comparing two strings. It's using information stored in the original hash (including a random "salt" string) to re-calculate a new hash from the user's input.